# st-json:write-json - avoid exponent markers for floats

Tags: common-lisp

```
(st-json:write-json-to-string
  (st-json:read-json "{\"a\":0.1}"))
```

Output is not valid JSON:

```
"{\"a\":1.e-1}"
```

Desired output:

```
"{\"a\":0.1}"
```

I don't see any options or other arguments for `write-json-to-string` at https://marijnhaverbeke.nl/st-json/

I would still be ok if the number came out a little modified like `.1` or `0.10`

Update: There is a system variable for float format: "The printer uses `*read-default-float-format*` to guide ***the choice of exponent markers*** when printing floating-point numbers."

According to this example ...

```
(let ((*read-default-float-format* 'double-float))
  (read-from-string "(1.0 1.0e0 1.0s0 1.0f0 1.0d0 1.0L0)"))

==> (1.0d0 1.0d0 1.0 1.0 1.0d0 1.0d0)
```

The implementation I'm using (SBCL 2.0.11) has float formats F and D. http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/v_rd_def.htm

I'm not sure how "The printer uses `*read-default-float-format*` to guide the choice of exponent markers when printing floating-point numbers." ... Is there something wrong with my test below?

```
 (progn
   (setf *read-default-float-format* 'long-float)
   (princ(st-json:write-json-to-string (st-json:read-json "{\"a\":0.1}")))
   (setf *read-default-float-format* 'single-float)
   (princ(st-json:write-json-to-string (st-json:read-json "{\"a\":0.1}")))
   (setf *read-default-float-format* 'double-float)
   (princ(st-json:write-json-to-string (st-json:read-json "{\"a\":0.1}")))
   (setf *read-default-float-format* 'short-float)
   (princ(st-json:write-json-to-string (st-json:read-json "{\"a\":0.1}"))))
   
 {"a":1.e-1}{"a":1.e-1}{"a":1.e-1}{"a":1.e-1}
 ==> "{\"a\":1.e-1}"
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It got nothing to do with `*read-default-float-format*`.

Using `M-.` in SLIME, I could see that `write-json-to-string` calls `write-json` which in turn calls `write-json-element`.

`write-json-element` is a generic function with different methods for different type. method for `real` is:

```lisp
(defmethod write-json-element ((element real) stream)
  (format stream "~,,,,,,'eE" element))
```

That format string is standard Common Lisp, resulting in the behaviour you are seeing.

```lisp
CL-USER> (format t "~,,,,,,'eE" 0.1)
1.e-1
NIL
CL-USER>
```

I have no idea why author did that, but if you are stuck with `st-json`, Just redefine the method as (which will issue a re-definition warning, but ignore that):

```lisp
(defmethod st-json:write-json-element ((element real) stream)
  (format stream "~F" element))
```

However, if you could switch to another library, take a look at [jzon](https://github.com/Zulu-Inuoe/jzon), it is in latest Quicklisp.